# Can't type my pass in "terminal" to install steam

Tags: command-line, steam

Good day!
Can't type my pass in "terminal" to install steam.

Steam installer promt to start it to complete installation
I press "Start"
A window dubbed "Terminal" pops
And there it says "Steam needs to install additional packages:
yadayada
[sudo] password for username:

Here comes the problem.
I can't type there
I can't copy-past from elsewhere

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You mean nothing appears? If so that's normal, just type it and press enter...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu terminal will not show *(star) or even white space while you typing password.
just type and press enter.

Comment: No, Ubuntu terminal will show _nothing_ while typing password..

Comment: ha ha .. thats what i said @heemayl i edited my answer

Comment: I saw the magic. Than you for help. How do I close\delete my duplicate question? :c

Comment: hey i am new here may be @heemayl  can help you. glad to hear that your problem is solved.

Comment: @ChristyJames downvote removed as the answer is clear now.. upvoted too..

Comment: @ChristyJames welcome to AskUbuntu.. please have a read.. http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @LenaRushkina please select the answer as accepted by clicking the tick mark on the left of the answer so that this issue can be marked as solved..